# Angularjs Placeholder (Attribute) Containing Smart Quote

Tags: angularjs, placeholder

I want to set the placeholder of an editable text area based on a value set in the controller.  The placeholder text contains smart quotes.  When I do this it works:

```
<div>
    <p editable-textarea="vm.address" e-rows="8" e-name="address" e-ng-model="vm.address" e-ng-maxlength="vm.addressLimit" 
       e-maxlength="{{vm.addressLimit}}" e-placeholder="They&rsquo;re">{{vm.address || '(empty)'}} </p>
</div>
```

This is displayed: "They’re".
However if I set e-placeholder to value defined in my controller it doesn't.  For example if the controller has

```
vm.addressPlaceholder = 'They&rsquo;re';
```

and the view

```
<div>
    <p editable-textarea="vm.address" e-rows="8" e-name="address" e-ng-model="vm.address" e-ng-maxlength="vm.addressLimit" 
       e-maxlength="{{vm.addressLimit}}" e-placeholder="{{vm.addressPlaceholder}}">{{vm.address || '(empty)'}} </p>
</div>
```

`They&rsquo;re` is displayed.  Any idea on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your value in quotes when you set it...

```
vm.addressPlaceholder = 'They&rsquo;re'
```

and then remove the curly braces and set it in the markup like so

```
e-placeholder="vm.addressPlaceholder"
```

Comment: My post should have contained quotes.  Removing the curly braces treats the vm.addressPlaceholder as a vale as opposed to a variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had single quotes in there as well that shouldn't have been...do you get the same behavior if you remove the single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.  The problem had to do with the encoding.  The javascript file was saved as ANSI.  After changing the encoding to UTF-8, problem resolved.